# show SQL results in a stacked bar chart in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I need help in writing a SQL query to show the results in horizontal a stacked bar chart in MS Excel. 
The data exist in SQL server db and it should be retrieved by SQL statement. The data looks like the following:

#### Valve     Status       period

1        NoReply     01-Mar-2021 14:10:40  
 1        NoReply     03-Mar-2021 16:04:02  
 1        NoReply     04-Mar-2021 18:09:40  
 1        NoReply     05-Mar-2021 02:01:02  
 1        BadReply    05-Mar-2021 14:10:40  
 1        BadReply    05-Mar-2021 16:04:02  
 1        BadReply    06-Mar-2021 14:10:40  
 1        BadReply    07-Mar-2021 16:04:02  
 1        NoReply     08-Mar-2021 14:10:40  
 1        NoReply     08-Mar-2021 16:04:02  
 1        NoReply     09-Mar-2021 18:09:40  
 1        NoReply     10-Mar-2021 02:01:02  
 1        NoData     10-Mar-2021 14:10:40   
 1        NoData     11-Mar-2021 16:04:02   
 1        NoData     12-Mar-2021 14:10:40   
 1        NoData     13-Mar-2021 16:04:02

2       .......  
2       .......

I want to show status of the valve in a horizontal stacked bar chart as shown below
Where X represents the period's length of the first status before the second status starts,
and Y represents the period's length of second status before the third status starts and so on.
Note the third status could be the same of the first status. And the length of the status should proportional to its period.
Any help is appreciated

Valve 
5    I  
4    I  
3    I
2    I   YYYYYXXXYYYYXXMMMXXXX
1    I   XXXXXYYYYYYYXXXXXUUUUUUU
_____________________________________________________________ 
DateTime     MM:DD:HH:MM             MM:DD:HH:MM    MM:DD:HH:MM  
in 
vertical

Comment: What is your DBMS? You'll find a lot of Gaps and Islands Problem solutions for different DBMSes here.

Comment: It is a SQL server database.